# validating forms $refs returning undefined vuejs

Tags: forms, vue.js, validation, vuejs2, ref

I am trying to validate my form but when I try to call the validation method it's returning the value undefined instead of Boolean. Can anyone help me fix the problem ? This below code is the one I am using to validate. By the way I am trying validate it in a child component. Which is only gonna render and show a dialogue when clicking a button.

```
   computed:{
        employeeFormValidation(){
          this.$refs.employeeForm.validate((valid)=>{
            return valid ? true : false
        },
        employeeAddressValidation(){
          this.$refs.employeeAddress.validate((valid)=>{
            return valid ? true : false
          })
        },
        employeeDetailsValidation(){
          this.$refs.employeeDetails.validate((valid)=>{
            return valid ? true : false
          })
        },
        bankDetailsValidation(){
          this.$refs.bankDetails.validate((valid)=>{
            return valid ? true : false
        })
        },
```

Comment: You should use the standard `:rules` prop that is available in Vuetify and Quasar. It's a bit different in ElementUI but in all 3 validation happens on the form level rather than on fields level. The form uses the rules to validate each field - and if all fields are valid then the whole form is considered valid and the promise will resolve. The child components will also be handled by the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue is not design as everything is reactive, the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) says "`$refs` is also non-reactive"

One way to do is use `methods` instead of `computed`, But the downside is that this will be re-called even if the dependency has not changed.

However, according to Vue's design philosophy, it should use less `refs`, accept the values emited by the component, and store them in `data`.

```html
<your-child-components
   @validate="(ok) => (valiateEmployeeDetails = ok)"
>
<your-child-components
   @validate="(ok) => (valiateEmployeeAddress = ok)"
>
```

```js
{
  data(){
    return {
      valiateEmployeeDetails: false,
      valiateEmployeeAddress: false,
    }
  }
}
```

---

`React` has a [doucment](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) about "when to use `refs`", it's the same in Vue.